# Как перенести свою верстку товара в файл single-product.php woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Начал осваивать Wordpress, используя плагин woocommerce. Не могу понять - как мне перенести свою верстку в файл single-product.php, чтобы с WordPress тянулась информация из карточки товаров.

На странице товара есть:
1)Название товара
2)2 слайдера (for/nav)
3)4 атрибута
4)Цена
5)Описание

Информации работы вывода из карточки товара WordPress нужных данных в файл single-product.php не нашёл - только работа в самом WordPress.[image: как должно выводиться на сайт после работы с файлом single-product.php woocommerce'a]

```html
<h2>Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса,<br> Истринский р-н, д. Котово</h2>



<div class="projcet-hole-place">
  <div class="proj-slaid">

    <div class="slider-for">
      <div class="slider-for__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/ms1.jpg" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>

      <div class="slider-for__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/ms2.jpg" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-for__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/ms3.jpg" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-for__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/slaid4 .png" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-for__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/slaid4 .png" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
    </div>





    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div class="slider-nav__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/ms1.jpg" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>

      <div class="slider-nav__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/ms2.jpg" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-nav__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/ms3.jpg" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-nav__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/slaid4 .png" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-nav__img">
        <img src="./assets/img/vladmoskslaid/slaid4 .png" alt="Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj-main-info">
    <h4>Дом из оцилиндрованного бруса</h4>
    <div class="proj-main-info__item-place">
      <div class="proj-main-info__item">
        <p class="space">Площадь по осям</p><span>174 м<sup>2</sup></span>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-main-info__item">
        <p class="dime">Размер строения</p><span>10х10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-main-info__item">
        <p class="mater">Материал стен</p><span>Оцилиндрованные брус</span>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-main-info__item">
        <p class="time">Срок сдачи объекна под ключ</p><span>от 3 до 5 месяцев</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="proj-price">
      <h6>от 170 000 ₽</h6>
      <a class="but-hov" href="#">Заказать консультацию</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="proj-informate__p">
  <p>Мы оптимизировали и улучшили еще один строительсный проект — современный дом из оцилиндрованного бруса. Что изменилось в доме?</p>

  <p>Увеличилась его площадь, внутренние помещения стали больше, а планировки — эргономичнее. На 1-м этаже мы изменили расположение лестницы — теперь она занимает меньше объема по высоте, так как находится в низкой части дома. Окна кухни и гостиной в новом
    проекте обращены в сад, а окна гостевой спальни-кабинета — на сторону входа. Прихожая стала больше и функциональнее.</p>

  <p>На втором этаже мы увеличили спальни, а в одной из них появилась собственная гардеробная.</p>

  <p>Теперь выходить подышать свежим воздухом или выпить чашку кофе куда приятнее и спокойнее.</p>

  <p>Фасады тоже преобразились.</p>

  <p>Увеличились количество и размеры окон. Окна теперь украшают все фасады (ранее в проекте был один глухой фасад).</p>

  <p>Под коньком и свесами кровли мы добавили декоративные элементы.</p>

  <p>А еще теперь есть возможность опционально заказать к данному дому угловую террасу с навесом.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Начни отсюда https://woocommerce.com/documentation/woocommerce-codex/theming/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После копания в закромах инета и помощи коллееги смог найти ответ на свой вопрос

```
<?php
get_header();
the_post(); //Обращение к посту из Worpress
global $product; // Создание Глобальной переменной для вытягивание нужной 
//информации в будущем
?>
<h2><?= the_title();?></h2> //Выведение названия товара 

<div class="slider-for"> //Выведени картинок для слайдеров из галереи
  <?php 
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
        foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id) : ?>
                <div class="slider-for__img">
                <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id); ?>" 
                class="page_products_slide" data-fancybox="gallery">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id); ?>" 
                alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </a>
                </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>


 <div class="proj-main-info__item">
    <p class="space">Площадь по осям</p><span><?= $product-> 
    get_attribute('Площадь') ?> м<sup>2</sup></span> // Выведение атрибутов
  </div>
```